# Error after applying the theme in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a newbie at an android studio. I started learning android a few days back. I started with simple blank activity and learning from New-Boston tutorial. Though I just applied theme right after executing the app I got some following errors.

[image: Error after applying the theme]

**STYLE.XML code:**

```
 <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </resources>
```

**Layout: Main Activity code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.wardahamk.changingtheme.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/include" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Layout: content activity code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.wardahamk.changingtheme.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Gradle Script:build.gradle (Project: changing theme):**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**Gradle Script: build.gradle(Module App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wardahamk.changingtheme"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I've been digging for the solution, but couldn't sort out. I'd be very thankful if you help me to find out the solution. Thanks a ton in advanced!

Comment: Can you please add your layout and styles.xml file.

Comment: @Anksss for certain!

Comment: Are you using AppCompat from the support library?

Comment: I couldnt get you. @Anksss

Comment: an issue is related to your coordinate layout if you change your parent layout then it will get resolved. can you please check your dependencies, might be there is multiple versions of app compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme.

Comment: I changed it in Style.xml but the errors were same as before.

Comment: Are you using your AppTheme.NoActionBar style somewhere? You need to set his parent too.

Comment: Please post your gradle

Answer (score 1):

Add tools:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" in your parent tag i.e

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   tools:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
   tools:context="com.example.wardahamk.changingtheme.MainActivity"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think it will work for you